# Are there any possibilities integrate Jasper server with WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2

Are there any posibilities integrate Jasper server with WSO2 IS ? I want to login to JS using IS and SSO with my other wso2 products also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperServer directly support for CAS. We are not supporting CAS yet, but we have a plan to implement this within next few releases [1]

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2901